# How do I integrate this $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{3x^{2} + 2x - 1}}$?

Tags: integration

Tried complete the square within the $x$ and trigonometry substitution. The additional $x$ mess my workings up. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: I tried complete the square within the square root, then a Tan theta substitute. 
But the additional x outside the square root, Kinda mess thing up.

P.S. I am self learning A-Level Maths here.

Comment: Please put your attempts in the body of the question.

Comment: After trig sub, you should get a rational function of trigonometric functions. With such expressions, the [half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) usually finishes up the problem. I suggest trying this.

Comment: Here is some obligatory advice on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) at this site.

Comment: @TobyMak Or [Guidelines for attracting Answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813), easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Suppose WLOG that $x > 0$. Then we can express the integrand as

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x\sqrt{3x^{2} + 2x - 1}} = \frac{1}{x^{2}\sqrt{3 + \dfrac{2}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}}
\end{align*}

Hence, if you make the change of variable $u = 1/x$, we arrive at the following integral:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{3x^{2} + 2x - 1}} & = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}\sqrt{3 + \dfrac{2}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}}\\
& = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}(1/x)}{\sqrt{3 + \dfrac{2}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x^{2}}}}\\
& = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{3 + 2u - u^{2}}}\\\\
& = -\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{4 - (u - 1)^{2}}}
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $3x^2+2x-1=(3x-1)(x+1)$, prompting the following substitution

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sqrt{3x^{2} + 2x - 1}}dx
\overset{t=\frac{x+1}{3x-1}}=-\int \frac1{\sqrt t(1+t)}dt=-2\tan^{-1}\sqrt t+ C
$$